# How to print all recorded plots in a list in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

this is my first question at StackOverflow. If I am doing something wrong let me know to improve the next questions.

I am starting with R Markdown and I have some troubles to print recorded plots with a for loop. Well, before I run Rmarkdown file, I run R function that generate a list of several data frames and plots.

To make it easier I put here a simplified reproducible example of this list just with plot objects.

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
y <- c(1,2,3,4,5)


plot(x,y)
abline(h=1)
p1.1 <- recordPlot()

plot(x,y)
abline(h=3)
p1.2 <- recordPlot()

plot(x,y)
abline(h=4)
p2.1 <- recordPlot()

plot(x,y)
abline(h=6)
p2.2 <- recordPlot()

lista<-NULL
lista["p1.1"] <- list(p1.1)
lista["p1.2"] <- list(p1.2)
lista["p2.1"] <- list(p2.1)
lista["p2.2"] <- list(p2.2)

save(new_list, file = "Data.RData")
```

Then I load this list in R Markdown file like this:

````
```{r setup}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE,fig.keep = "all")
load("Data.RData")```
````

And I try to print this plots like this:

````
```{r,echo=FALSE, results='asis',fig.keep='all'}
for (i in c(1,2)){
 for(j in c(1,2)){
  print(lista[[paste(paste("p",i,sep=""),j,sep=".")]])
 }
}```
````

When I run Knitr to obtain HTML file the result is that just the last plot of the for loop is shown.

I have tried use lapply instead of for loop, but it did not work for me. Also I tried to use replayPlot function `print(replayPlot(lista[[paste(paste(paste("p",i,sep=""),".",sep=""),j,sep="")]]))` with the same result.

Is there any way to solve this without modifying the previous R function that generate the plot list?

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: length(lista)==4 right? Not sure the 4*4 double loop produces what you expect.

Comment: thanks for the answere. it was an error creating a reproducible example. I have edited the code. I have changed length(list) for c(1,2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you use would probably be OK with a list of `ggplot` objects, but with base `plot` objects, you need to call `plot.new()` so that the next plot in the list doesn't overwrite the previous one:

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

## Define plots

```{r}
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
y <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

plot.new()
plot(x,y)
abline(h=1)
p1.1 <- recordPlot()

plot.new()
plot(x,y)
abline(h=3)
p1.2 <- recordPlot()

plot.new()
plot(x,y)
abline(h=4)
p2.1 <- recordPlot()

plot.new()
plot(x,y)
abline(h=6)
p2.2 <- recordPlot()

lista<-NULL
lista["p1.1"] <- list(p1.1)
lista["p1.2"] <- list(p1.2)
lista["p2.1"] <- list(p2.1)
lista["p2.2"] <- list(p2.2)

```

# Print list

```{r,echo=F}
for (i in c(1,2)){
 for(j in c(1,2)){
  # Needed to avoid overwrite
  plot.new()
  print(lista[[paste(paste("p",i,sep=""),j,sep=".")]])
 }
}
```
````

Note that you can simplify the syntax of the loops:

```
for(p in lista) {
  plot.new()
  print(p)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop to plot each ggplot saved in a list. Much simpler:

````
```{r,echo=FALSE}
  print(lista)
```
````

This automatically plots every element of the list (each plot) to the Markdown.