# Is there a way to call all plots in the current environment in R?

Tags: r

I have a lot of plots named "plt_xxxx" and I would like to plot all of them in a loop.

I tried this code but it did not work. When I run the code nothing happens, no error.

```
pltEnv <- ls()[grepl("plt_", ls())]
for(x in pltEnv){
  get(x)
}
```

When I run this code it works:

```
get(pltEnv[1])
get(pltEnv[2])
# ...
```

Comment: Can you give us a little more to go on? For example, what happens when you try this? An error? Nothing? You get some plots but not all you were expecting? Also, if you `dput(ls())` and paste that into your question, we can try to reproduce your issue. Also, your variable name is different in lines 1 and 2: line 1 is `pltEnv` and line 2 is `plt_in_env`.

Comment: If you want to plot the list using RMarkdown, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63366579/13513328) could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I ran `mget(pltEnv)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
plt_1 <- plotly::plot_ly(x=1, y = 1)
plot_names <- ls(pattern = "plt_.*")
eval(parse(text = plot_names[1]))
```

I would save my plot in a named list instead to access them later.